# Django form field for integer list and using it for ModelMultipleChoiceField

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, textinput

I would like to have a form field with TextInput widget (for example CharField) for recieving comma-separated positive integer lists, for example: **0, 1, 2,7, 645, 345, 1000**. I want to use it with ModelMultipleChoiceField (so the integer values represent pk). How could I achieve this? From the documentation it is not obvious how to create such field and how to make it work with ModelMultipleChoiceField (how to use the integer list returned from TextInput in ModelMultipleChoiceField to get the objects queryset).